# Is it possible to create a layout like this in Android..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I want to design a XML resource layout like traditional blogs as shown in the below image. It should contain an image on the right side and rest of the area (combining left side area of the image and whole area below the image) should be filled with text.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: use TableLayout

Comment: You could do this with two TextViews and an ImageView in a RelativeLayout...

Comment: @MichaelKrause, I want to achieve it in a single TextView.

Comment: You'll want to brush up on creating custom Views then.  TextView will not be able to do this for you since its workable space is rectangular.  You can create a custom View that will know how to layout variable width per line text as well as draw the image view where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)

[image]

Here is an snippet

```
<uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
    android:id="@+id/ftv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/android"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dip"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/android2"/>
</uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
```

and in code

```
FlowTextView flowTextView = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.ftv);
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml("<html>Your html goes here....");
flowTextView.setText(html);
```

Add jitpack to your your build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

Add the dependency:

```
compile 'com.github.deano2390:FlowTextView:2.0.5'
```

Comment: Thank You. That's exactly what I wanted. I don't understand why my question gets negative rating..

Comment: That is because you did not showed your tries. You should tell always what you have done so far.

Comment: Done. Still another problem. Can't use this...<div style='text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word;'> ...... <div> is not supported....I want to justify text like MS Word. Again any ideas..? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to brush up on creating custom Views then.

A single TextView will not be able to do this for you since its workable space is rectangular.

You can create a custom View that will know how to layout variable width per line text as well as draw the image view where you want it.

I recommend starting with what android.widget.TextView does to draw text and modify it to suit your needs.

Or, you can find a custom View that someone else has already written and componentized that you can use.